# Improving upon an existing object array to automate array creation

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm trying to create an easily updatable list of titles/urls that can populate various places on my website (blog posts).

I have a working version, but know it can be improved so I do not have to update the array creation manually each time I add a new class or blog page.

I have googled all the problems up until this point but can't seem to find a similar problem to this online. At the moment I have a for loop which is counted based on an iterating variable within the class constructor:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= $pageCount; $x++) {
    $pageList[] = '$page' . $x;
}
```

This way I'm able to get the right word that represents the variable, but not the value within the variable.

Class looks like this:

```
class BlogPage
{
    public $link;
    public $name;
    public $tags;

    public static $counter = 0;

    function __construct() {
        self::$counter++;
    }
}

$page0 = new BlogPage();
$page0->link = 'hike-safe';
$page0->name = 'How to Conquer the Mountains';
$page0->tags = "";

$page1 = new BlogPage();
$page1->link = 'how-to-map';
$page1->name = 'How to Read a Map and Compass';
$page1->tags = "";

$page2 = new BlogPage();
$page2->link = 'test';
$page2->name = 'Test thats a bit longer';
$page2->tags = "";

$pageCount = BlogPage::$counter - 1;

for ($x = 0; $x <= $pageCount; $x++) {
    $pageList[] = '$page' . $x;
}
```

This is the array that I would be manually updating:

```
$blogPages = array($page2, $page1, $page0);
```

How do I get around this variable conundrum?

Comment: Why not save instances ? - hhttp://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/969d75ded3383448af4830e4629d391006fc96d6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mention in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) you can use `{}` to create the var names dynamiclly.

Consider the following example:

```
$a0 = "AAA";
$a1 = "BBB";
$a2 = "CCC";
$cnt = 3;
$res = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++)
    $res[] = ${"a" . $i}; // will assign value of $a0, $a1, $a2 in each iteration
```

Now `$res` will contains:

```
Array
(
    [0] => AAA
    [1] => BBB
    [2] => CCC
)
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! thank you so much. saved me much grief.